# Irrationality measure of $\frac{\ln{3}}{\ln{2}}$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Is there anyone knows the irrationality measure of $\frac{\ln{3}}{\ln{2}}$? Since it's transcendental number, its  measure is $2$ or greater, and I have not found something relevant.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/166088/irrationality-measure-of-log2-log6 and references within

Comment: One would think the actual value is $2$, but the available bounds are not good enough.